# require css in React component affects other components too

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following `render` in my "main" component:

```
import ComponentA from './component-a.js'; 
import ComponentB from './component-b.js'; 
const App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentA/>
                <ComponentB/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

`ComponentA` requires a `css` file. So I have the following in `component-a.js`:

```
require ('./component-a.css');
const ComponentA = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>component a</div>
        );
    }
});
```

… whereas `ComponentB` doesn't. So I have the following in `component-b.js`:

```
const ComponentB = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>component b</div>
        );
    }
});
```

The `css` file required by `ComponentA` (only) is:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Even though it is only `ComponentA` that requires the `css`, `ComponentB` is also affected. This is what gets rendered in the browser:

[image]

It seems that all `div` elements in the page are affected by the style required by `ComponentA`. That includes the `div` of the subsequent component `ComponentB` (which does **not** require the `css` style) as well as the `div` that contains `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` and yet another `div` added by React:

[image]

1. Aren't `css` files affecting only the component that requires them? If not, and they are effectively global in effect then what exactly are the semantics of requiring a `css` file from a specific component ?
2. Other than using inline styles and placing everything in JS code, is there a way to compartmentalize CSS files so that they only affect the React component that requires them ? If one were to use class names to achieve that effect there is no guarantee that the class names would be unique when a component is used alongside other components.

Comment: React renders the component in HTML, thus any stylesheets linked in your HTML file with affect the rendered components

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CSS is still loaded into the browser to affect the whole page. The importing of css files is only to modularize your css along with your js, so that when you use your module loader to the fullest, not only are you not loading unnecessary js, you also aren't loading unnecessary css.

EDIT: a video on how Instagram works with module loading:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkTCL6Nqm6Y&noredirect=1

Your best solution is still to namespace your css. Concerning clashing issues, you could use even more verbose classnames than what I used below like `mjb-appname-componentname`

Have your ComonentA's render be:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="component-a">component a</div>
    );
}
```

and its css file be

```
.component-a div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

preferably with a css preprocessor like `less` or `sass`

```
.component-a {
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

extra:

an interesting talk about inline style in js:  http://blog.vjeux.com/2014/javascript/react-css-in-js-nationjs.html

a discussion about issues raised by using this inline style method:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4066

Comment: If you do end up going the verbose class names route, [BEM](http://getbem.com/) is a good approach to take. I tend to use a slight variant on it, capitalizing the block name if it corresponds to a component. e.g. `Component__element--modifier`.

Comment: > "*so that when you use your module loader to the fullest, not only are you not loading unnecessary js, you also aren't loading unnecessary css*".
¿When that happens?. Because I have css imports in components that are not rendered affecting components that **are** rendered. At least in development

Comment: @Madacol look up "code splitting", only worthwhile for large apps